# How to identify similar journey patterns and cluster these into groups in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'm trying to find a way of comparing 1000+ car journeys with each other in order to cluster similar journeys. (preferably in R)

In the example below, each row is one person's journey for a particular day.

Each column represents a point where the car stopped. Time is not taken in consideration, just the order in which the journey was made. e.g stop1, stop2, stop3 ... stop10

The data will contain NAs, as not all journeys had 10 stops.

Example:
Matrix (row.names represent a unique person):

```
row.names, stop1, stop2, stop3, stop4, stop5, stop6 ... stop10
    1        34     23     16    283     12    453  ...   
    2        34     23     16    283     12    453  ...   
    3        34     23     16    122     12    NA   ...   
    4        62     72     90    11      NA    NA   ...   
    5        62     90     11    NA      NA    NA   ...   
    6        46     39     46    83      73    3    ...
```

I'm new to clustering but have looked into different type (Kmeans, hierarchy).

I have tried using heatmaps and parellel coordinates but they have not yeilded the visuals I'm looking for - i.e. it's not easy to see the groups with over 1000+ journeys and I don't think it works well for journeys which may be similar to other.

I'm hoping someone can help provide an example of where they have clustered data similar to this and explain it so it is clear for a beginner?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset consists of locations, so it has a geographical dimension. Instead of just looking at numerical IDs, get the coordinates of each of those points and plot them. That will probably be much more informative than any simple clustering.

---

Alternatively, if geocoding is infeasible, you can treat this as an association rules (market basket analysis) problem. Each trip represents a basket, and the location IDs are the items present in each basket.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to geo data nor is it possible to decipher it from the current data. I'm interested in your suggestion about using the MB analysis approach. Could you provide more detail on how I would do this in R, in order to find similar journey patterns?